# Nuitka/Pyinstaller, unable to load oauth2client libraries and others

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gspread, oauth2client, nuitka

I'm relatively new to Python. For a school project, I'm coding a relatively complex program. I need to make an executable file. I started testing with a fraction of the actual program, and I was unable to create a .exe file using PyInstaller, Nuitka, Py2Exe and cx_freeze....

My last few attempts have been made using Nuitka.

Libraries I use:

- gspread
- oauth2client
- PyQt4
- serial
- threading
- time
- sys
- json

Here is what I get with Nuitka

```
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py:33: Cannot find 'six.moves' in package 'oauth2client' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py:1108: Cannot find 'google.appengine' in package 'oauth2client' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\oauth2client\appengine.py:28: Cannot find 'webapp2' in package 'oauth2client' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\oauth2client\appengine.py:30: Cannot find 'google.appengine.api' in package 'oauth2client' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\oauth2client\appengine.py:33: Cannot find 'google.appengine.ext' in package 'oauth2client' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\oauth2client\appengine.py:34: Cannot find 'google.appengine.ext.webapp.util' in package 'oauth2client' as absolute
import.Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\rsa\transform.py:28: Cannot find 'psyco' in package 'rsa' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_pycrypto_crypt.py:16: Cannot find 'Crypto.PublicKey' in package 'oauth2client' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_pycrypto_crypt.py:17: Cannot find 'Crypto.Hash' in package 'oauth2client' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_pycrypto_crypt.py:18: Cannot find 'Crypto.Signature' in package 'oauth2client' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_pycrypto_crypt.py:19: Cannot find 'Crypto.Util.asn1' in package 'oauth2client' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py:55: Cannot find 'socks' in package 'httplib2' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\gspread\httpsession.py:14: Cannot find 'urlparse' in package 'gspread' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py:29: Cannot find 'urllib3' in package 'requests.packages' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py:35: Cannot find 'chardet' in package 'requests.packages' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\response.py:2: Cannot find 'packages.six.moves' in package 'requests.packages.urllib3' 2 package levels up.Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\ssl_match_hostname\__init__.py:7: Cannot find 'backports.ssl_match_hostname' in package 'requests.packages.urllib3.packages.ssl_match_hostname' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py:13: Cannot find 'packages.six.moves' in package 'requests.packages.urllib3' 1 package level up.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\ordered_dict.py:11: Cannot find '_abcoll' in package 'requests.packages.urllib3.packages' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py:7: Cannot find 'urlparse' in package 'requests.packages.urllib3' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\requests\compat.py:37: Cannot find'urlparse' in package 'requests' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\requests\compat.py:38: Cannot find'urllib2' in package 'requests' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\requests\compat.py:39: Cannot find'cookielib' in package 'requests' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\requests\compat.py:40: Cannot find'Cookie' in package 'requests' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\requests\certs.py:17: Cannot find 'certifi' in package 'requests' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py:49: Cannot find 'ndg.httpsclient.ssl_peer_verification' in package 'requests.packages.urllib3.contrib' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py:50: Cannot find 'ndg.httpsclient.subj_alt_name' in package 'requests.packages.urllib3.contrib' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:Unresolved '__import__' call at 'C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py:303' may require use of '--recurse-directory'.
Nuitka:WARNING:Unresolved '__import__' call at 'C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py:308' may require use of '--recurse-directory'.
Nuitka:WARNING:Unresolved '__import__' call at 'C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py:310' may require use of '--recurse-directory'.
Nuitka:WARNING:Unresolved '__import__' call at 'C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py:74' may require use of '--recurse-directory'.
Nuitka:WARNING:Unresolved '__import__' call at 'C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\six.py:82' may require use of '--recurse-directory'.
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated

Comment: FWIW, I see python 3.4 referenced in the traceback, that's not supported on App Engine (yet), only 2.7 (and 2.5) are presently supported: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime; https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/migrate27.

Answer (score 0):

Ok

You need to go back to basics, first question is,  are really using appengine ?

If  you are using appengine then I suggest you start out by reading up on getting started with appengine and python and the sandbox as Nuitka will not run on appengine

Comment: I am not directly using App Engine.

The program works well from the python console.

Here is what the programs do:

- Opens a google spreadsheet using gspread
- Get information from a specific cell from the spreadsheet
- Update information of a specific cell on the spreadsheet


I tried on python 2.7, still getting tons of Warnings and exe doesn't work